# SharePoint Application Page - File not found exception

Tags: sharepoint, wspbuilder

I am developing a webpart in Visual Studio 2005 for SharePoint using a wspbuilder project template.

I deploy my pages,images,css and javascript files using WSPBuilder. Sometimes, I come across 'File not found' exception when I make a deploy using wspbuilder.

After some series of repetitive deploys, the page would work fine. I don't know what is the reason behind this. I am also including the stack trace of the exception which I got in the SharePoint Application Page.

> **Stack Trace**:- File Not Found.   at System.Reflection.Assembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection) 
>      at System.Reflection.Assembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection) 
>      at System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) 
>      at System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) 
>      at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) 
>      at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(String assemblyName, Boolean throwOnFail) 
>      at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.LoadAssembly(String assemblyName, Boolean throwOnFail) 
>      at System.Web.UI.MainTagNameToTypeMapper.ProcessTagNamespaceRegistrationCore(TagNamespaceRegisterEntry nsRegisterEntry) 
>      at System.Web.UI.MainTagNameToTypeMapper.ProcessTagNamespaceRegistration(TagNamespaceRegisterEntry nsRegisterEntry) 
>      at System.Web.UI.BaseTemplateParser.ProcessDirective(String directiveName, IDictionary directive) 
>      at System.Web.UI.TemplateControlParser.ProcessDirective(String directiveName, IDictionary directive) 
>      at System.Web.UI.PageParser.ProcessDirective(String directiveName, IDictionary directive) 
>      at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseStringInternal(String text, Encoding fileEncoding) 
>   Troubleshoot issues with Windows SharePoint Services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure your application page references the full assembly name, including version and public key token in its Page declaration